# I don't know what to do next with this exception when i run

Tags: c#, firebase

```
An error occurred while starting the application.
FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'D:\UNICEC_BE-master\UniCEC.API\unics-e46a4-firebase-adminsdk-td0dr-86cc1f1def.json'.
System.IO.FileStream.ValidateFileHandle(SafeFileHandle fileHandle)

FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'D:\UNICEC_BE-master\UniCEC.API\unics-e46a4-firebase-adminsdk-td0dr-86cc1f1def.json'.
System.IO.FileStream.ValidateFileHandle(SafeFileHandle fileHandle)
System.IO.FileStream.CreateFileOpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, int bufferSize, FileOptions options)
System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
System.IO.File.OpenRead(string path)
Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential.FromFile(string path)
UniCEC.API.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in Startup.cs
+
            FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(object target, object[] arguments, Signature sig, bool constructor, bool wrapExceptions)
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.InvokeCore(object instance, IServiceCollection services)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder+<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<Invoke>g__Startup|0(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.Invoke(object instance, IServiceCollection services)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder+<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<Build>b__0(IServiceCollection services)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.UseStartup(Type startupType, HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services, object instance)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder+<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<UseStartup>b__0(HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
UniCEC.API.Program.Main(string[] args) in Program.cs
+
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();[enter image description here]
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Dx1m.png)

I received a project and it seems that it is not connected to the server. And I don't know what's in the other .json file.

Comment: I strongly suspect that you've got a `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable (or something in your configuration file) specifying that filename as a service account JSON file. You need a suitable credential *somewhere* - we don't really know enough about your context to know whether you should ask for *that* credential file or create a new one.

Comment: I think i need create a new JSON file.

Comment: Okay. In that case you might want to start with [the service account documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts). Note that if you run your code on Google Cloud Platform (e.g. Cloud Run, Compute Engine etc) then you don't need a separate service account - there's one that will be used by default. (You'd just need to clear the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.)